# SugarCRM Studio Module Fields Throwing oData is null Error

Tags: php, oop, open-source, sugarcrm

I had added field to Leads Module through Studio in SugarCRM 6.4 CE and then Deleted the field from Code. Now when i go to studio and list fields for Leads Module it throws Error

> `oData` is `null`.

Can any body explain why this is happening and how can I get the list of fields back?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by setting the labels of all module fields